# Ruby on Rails Access to object in array passed as param

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm sendig from my client side an array of objects, using ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
              type:    "POST",
              url:     "http://localhost:3000/ventas/",
              data:    {detalles: detalles},
              success: function(post){ console.log("Ok") },
              error:   function(post){ console.log(this) }
            });
```

and in my server i am receving this parameters (line of server console):

```
Parameters: {"detalles"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"249", "cantidad"=>"2", "importe"=>"40"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"382", "cantidad"=>"2", "importe"=>"470"}}}
```

now i want to acces to each object of this array, this is my try:

```
def  create
    @details= params[:detalles]
    puts @details["0"]
end
```

everythig is ok but how can I iterate through all the objects? because "0" is a string , and if i put just 0 it does no work. How can i loop trough @details and acces to each object and then to its attributes?. thanks

Comment: `@details` is a hash. `Hash` is [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html). The latter could be iterated with e.g. `each`.

Comment: @mudasobwa excatly. He has to use the method for the `Enumerable` class

Answer (score -2):

thanks to @mudasobwa and @Fabrizio Bertoglio.
the right answer is that:
for iterate a hash of objects:

```
def create
 @details.each { |x| puts @details["#{x}"] }
end
```

for iterate a has of objects and access to its atributtes:

```
 def create
 @details.each { |x| puts @details["#{x}"][:importe] }
end
```

Comment: Nope, this is not a right way. One might go check the documentation for [`Hash#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-each) and see that the iteration block yields _the key-value pair already_: `@details.each { |_, v| puts v }`. The lookup by key is redundant and way less performing.

Comment: ok can you add the code for my case please? Answer it and i put it as the right answer, thanks